# LaTeX: Can I use a setting file to change some common parameters shared among different template files?

Tags: parameters

I have several template files used for journal articles, such as for review, article, case report, etc.  These templates have similar file structures.  I realized that some common parameters need be changed when I am working on a new issue of the journal.  For example, the templates all have "January 2016, Volume 1 Issue 1" and now I am working on Issue 2 so I need to remember changing this phrase to "April 2016, Volume 1 Issue 2" for every manuscript.

Is there a way to create a setting file, so I can change such shared information at one place and be used by all the template files?

Comment: For example you could create a `.tex` file with `\date{April 2016}` and then call it from all the other files with `\input{filename}`. Is this what you intend?

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense to me. I will give it a try and let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The standard latex convention would be to call your settings a *package*.

put them in (say) `mysettings.sty`

```
\newcommand\something{...}
\setlength\textwidth{2pt}
 %....
```

then each of your documents just needs

```
\usepackage{mysettings}
```